# Finishing MySQL prepared statement in JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I am learning MySQL with JAVA, and don't understand prepared statements. Abstracting from I shall learn it, I want to ask for help in finishing this code to be "prepared stated" :-)

```
String stringQuery = "INSERT INTO banlist (name, reason, admin, time, temptime, IP) VALUES (testNick, testPowod, testAdmin, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, NOW(), NULL);=?";

PreparedStatement statement = this.connection.prepareStatement( stringQuery );
statement.setString( 1,  ); // after ' 1, ' we define what we want to get
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Are you  having any issues while running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String stringQuery = 
    "INSERT INTO banlist (name, reason, admin, time, temptime, IP)"
    + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, NOW(), NULL)";

PreparedStatement statement = this.connection.prepareStatement(stringQuery);
statement.setString(1, testNick);
statement.setString(2, testPowod);
statement.setString(3, testAdmin);
int inserted = statement.executeUpdate();
```

Read the [JDBC tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO banlist(name, reason, admin, time, temptime, IP) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement statement = this.connection.prepareStatement( stringQuery );
statement.setString(1, name);  // These values come from your code; dynamic
statement.setString(2, reason);
statement.setString(3, admin);
statement.setString(4, time);
statement.setString(5, tempTime);
statement.setString(6, ip); 
int numRowsAffected = statement.executeUpdate();
```

Be sure to close your statement appropriately.